# Can create a selector for viewWillAppear but not for viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not seeing why this will compile:

```
let viewWillAppearSelector = #selector(UIViewController.viewWillAppear(_:))
```

But not this:

```
let viewDidLoadSelector = #selector(UIViewController.viewDidLoad())
```

The error is

> "Use of instance member 'viewDidLoad' on type UIViewController; did
>   you mean to use  a value type 'UIViewController' instead?

Why does the latter not complile but the former does?

Update: I changed it to this and now it compiles:

```
let viewDidLoadSelector = #selector(UIViewController.viewDidLoad)
```

But I'm not 100% why that is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a method does not take any parameters you need to omit the parentheses. In a future version of Swift your code will become an error.

Try

```
let viewDidLoadSelector = #selector(UIViewController.viewDidLoad)
```

instead.